# May i config healthMonitoring for classic asp in ii7?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic, health-monitoring

I see that for showing error of classic asp in ii7 i must use web.config with configurations for asp.net like this:

```
<system.webServer>
                <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
                <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
            </system.webServer>
```

BUT:

may i use healthMonitoring in classic asp for getting email errors about bugs in classic asp?

tried it by cant get any emails :( simply do redirect to homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot use the ASP.NET Health Monitoring for "classic" ASP sites.

This page, [asp Element - IIS 7 Settings Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689477.aspx) on the MSDN website details all of the different attributes to the `<asp>` node within the `<system.webServer>` node, and unfortunately, there does not seem to be a mechanism for switching on health monitoring.

This makes sense as the `<system.webServer>` node is processed by, and defines configuration for IIS7 itself rather than the ASP.NET runtime, whereas the Health Monitoring functionality is ASP.NET specific, and it is even implemented by classes within the .NET framework's [System.Web.Management Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.aspx).

That said, if you're looking to be alerted, via email, whenever an error occurs within your classic ASP application, you could achieve this by setting the `errorsToNTLog` attribute of the `<asp>` node to `True`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" errorsToNTLog="True" />
</system.webServer>
```

This will ensure that ASP errors occurring within your application will be logged to the Windows Event Log.  You can then monitor these errors using a separate utility which will fire off an email notification to you when an event log entry is written.

A detailed explanation of how this can be achieved, and the various options for tools (open-source, commercial or even a custom VBScript) needed to perform this, can be found within this ServerFault posting:

[Windows Event Log - email notification](https://serverfault.com/questions/47953/windows-event-log-email-notification)